# Xaml - How to inject a Canvas StaticResource into a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

On Windows Phone 8 I have a few canvas item StaticResources that I'd like to inject into a DataTemplate but can't quite figure out how to do it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here's a distilled version of my XAML so far:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <Canvas x:Key="Item1">
        ...
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas x:Key="Item2">
        ...
    </Canvas>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate">
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Viewbox Height="96" Width="96" Margin="0,12,12,0">
                <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Item1}" />
            </Viewbox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

When run I get an unhandled exception of:
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have controls as resources. One UI element cannot be in two places of the visual tree at the same time, so that makes it pointless to have controls as resources.

Here's an idea, but I'm not sure how it will perform if you use a lot of these resources. I tested it quickly and it seems to work, but I haven't used it for real, so there might be some issues in some cases.

1. Wrap the Canvas from the resources in a DataTemplate like this:

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="Item1">
       <Canvas>
           ...
       </Canvas>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
2. Use this template for ContentControl's **ContentTemplate** property like this:

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate">
       ...
          <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Item1}" />
       ...
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @Gavin Hmm, that's very strange. It is working fine for me, and I tested with a quite complex Canvas. Anyway, I see you found a solution that works for you, which is what's important. :) If you want me to check why my suggestion is not working, you could share the code for the Canvas that you tried (by editing your answer or give a link to pastebin here in the comments).

Comment: @Gavin There's no chance that you've changed the ContentControl's style (as suggested by Sheridan (good one btw)), while testing my idea, right? If not it should be displaying exactly what's on the Canvas that you want (maybe not in the expected size).

Comment: @Gavin I did test it in a WP8.0 app, and it was working fine. Am I missing something or the Canvases are not inside a DataTemplate as I suggested? My idea is basically this: Make a DataTemplate with the Canvas in it and then set that DataTemplate as a ContentTemplate of a ContentControl. Is this what you've tried?

Comment: @Gavin I can see from pastebin that you didn't put a DataTemplate around the Canvases. Check this out: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GBBs9QTS). This is working for me in a WP8.0 app. You can put the Viewbox in the DataTemplate as well, so wherever you use it, you'll just have to specify the size of the ContentControl. Oh, and sorry for bothering you with this, I just think my solution is a good one (being shorter than the others) and it would help people.

Comment: @Gavin Haha, well it happens to everyone sometimes, no problem. Glad I could help and that you find my solution to be a good one. :) Oh, and the app looks nice, good luck with it! :)

Comment: @Gavin One last thing: I think we should delete most of the comments above as they are of no use to anyone else reading this. (Including this comment, of course)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be somewhat confused as to how WPF works. You cannot *inject* `Canvas` controls from resources into XAML. The best that you can do is to create a `Style` for your `Canvas` and then apply that `Style` to a new `Canvas` in your XAML. However, it should be noted that you cannot set the `Canvas.Children` property from that `Style`... this would cause an error:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
    <Setter Property="Children">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Button Content="Click me!!" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, it *is* possible to 'pre-define' controls in a `Style`, but you would have to use a `ContentControl` to display it. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Canvas>
                    <Button Content="Click me!!" />
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now when you can see the `Button` in the `Canvas` whenever you use this XAML:

```
<ContentControl />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Margin="10" Background="AliceBlue">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas>
                            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}" Text="{Binding Text}" Width="50" Height="20" Foreground="Black"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```